# How to enable vs code terminal?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

This may be a really basic question but I am not clear how to proceed. I have started using python in datacamp courses but now moving to my own terminal is giving me some issues. When I open VS code and open the file I want to work the terminal does not allow me to write, it just appears a path, I tried to run a simple code but it does not run, basically happen anything. Do you know if I have to do something specific before start running the code to enable the terminal?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
year = [1950, 1970, 1990, 2010]
pop = [2.519, 3.692, 5.563, 6.972]
plot1 = plt.scatter(year, pop)
plt.show()
```

And this is what I see on the screen, below the path highlighted in yellow the terminal does not allow to write

[image: Screenshot]

I Appreciate any suggestion, Thanks

Comment: Do you see the plot appear in a separate window once you run the code? I'm not really sure what you're expecting to happen. The program is not asking for an input anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

The terminal is working fine, but there is currently a program running in it!

You called Python to execute your `clase.py` file. So, all input/output you do in the terminal will now go to/come from your Python program that you just called, not your shell.

You can either wait for the program to be finished (you will get another prompt then) or press Ctrl+C to abort your program. Since your program looks like it's outputting a plot somewhere, I'd assume it opens a new window for that - in this case, the terminal will return to the prompt once that window is closed.

If you need a second terminal to do something else while the program is running in the first, you can click the "+" button to open a second terminal (you can switch using the dropdown), or the "split" button right next to the "+" to open the second one at the side.